# How to "hook" into methods?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm working on a game in XNA, and I don't want to keep putting a bunch of code in the main file inside the Draw and Update methods. Is there a way I could just run one "master" method inside one, for example:

```
 protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Instead of having to do Tools.DrawModel() for every model 
        // I have to draw, can I do this?
        Tools.MasterDraw();
    }
 // Inside MasterDraw:
 public static void MasterDraw()
 {
        // A bunch of Tools.DrawModel() goes here, but instead of repeating
        // it every time for every model, how would I make a function 
        // to auto-add a line to draw itself inside this function????
 }
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a loop that iterates through all the models, calling your draw method on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XNA, you can define one `Draw` method for each object you have, if they derive from `DrawableGameComponent`, which will be called automatically.

So basically your Tool class should look like:

```
public class Tool : DrawableGameComponent
{
    public Tool(Game game) : base(game)
    {
        game.Components.Add(this);        
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        base.Draw(gameTime);

        // Put draw logic for your tool here
    }
}
```

You need to implement the constructor (which receives `Game`) and add your stuff to the `Game.Components` list. Adding your object to the components is what triggers the automated calls to `Draw`.

You can also override `Update` to avoid putting everything in the `Game1` loop.

You should also give a good look to [MSDN's Starter Kit: Platformer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254918%28v=xnagamestudio.31%29.aspx), since you don't really seem familiar with XNA. That pattern is implemented in the basic tutorial.

Comment: Can you explain to me what the "public Tool(Game game) : base(game)" part is doing? What's the stuff in the parenthesis and how do they work? Sorry I am fairly new to C# and the last language I learned was Lua, and it's taking me a while to grasp this concept of "object oriented programming"

Comment: @user3841476 That's the class constructor, which is called on your class creation. The 'stuff in parenthesis' are the arguments passed. Since this class is derived from DrawableGameComponent, and that class needs the Game instance, you must pass it to it. You'll get much more detailed explanations on MSDN. The Starter Kit tutorial is also essential if you want to do more serious XNA.

Comment: When I create a new instance of the class with the code you gave me, it's asking me for an argument (which is the Game class). What do I give it?

Comment: @user3841476 If you're creating it from Game1, pass it `this`. This keyword means "the current class". If you look at the declaration of Game1, you'll see it's extending Game. If you're creating it from an other class, that class will need to have a reference to Game. It's annoying, but how XNA's work. I again suggest you take a deep look at the basic tutorial, I mean, it's all there.